Is this enthalpy diagram right when ammonium nitrate decomposes?
Q1) I wonder if this enthalpy diagram is right when ammonium nitrate decomposes(without using enthalpy of formation).

Q2) If my enthalpy diagram is right, I have a question about the ionization energy and electron affanity of polyatomic ions which have the resonance structures. In the case of nitrate ion, all of the resonance structures contribute equally. But when resonance structures contribute not equally like thioformate ion, how to decide the ionization energy or electron affanity of the ion?

There seem to be some errors in the diagram. What is your source for those data?

The passage from $\ce{NH4}$ to $\ce{NH4+}$ is not the ionization energy of the nitrogen atom.
The passage from $\ce{NO3-}$ to $\ce{NO3}$ is not minus the electron affinity of the oxygen atom.
And I am not sure that neutral arrangements like $\ce{NH4}$ and $\ce{NO3}$ do exist and can be used in such a diagram.
